# What is the origin of BSO - and is it internationally recognized?

Tags: terminology, bso

Who is the first person who came up with the appellation, **"Bicycle Shaped Object" (BSO)** referring to very inexpensive and very poorly built bicycles sold through mass-market department stores?

**Bonus question:** And is it international? We use BSO in America and I've heard b.se members from Australia and New Zealand use it, but is it used in the UK and Canada? What do people in France or Japan or other countries call BSOs?

<sub>If the bonus question makes this question *too broad* then I'll withdraw the bonus and make it a separate question.</sub>

Comment: I would assume that in France they call it the O de BS.

Comment: I've been accused of having eau de BS!

Comment: Note that bicycle shaped object doesn't appear in google ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bicycle+shaped+object&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: When given in its full form it's self-explanatory, and would be understood by any native speaker with a concept of varying quality in bikes. The style fits well with British engineering parlance (I've heard bad tools described in almost identical terms by old hands). But I picked it up here, and my father, who's been cycling in the UK since the 60s, doesn't seem to have come across it until recently.

Comment: Neither does it appear on ShledonBrown.com, even in the [glossary](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/glossary-b.html).  That seems surprising and to me suggests a fairly recent coinage, or a UK source. (note that googling `BSO site:sheldonbrown.com` *does* return hits, but they're music-related)

Comment: I think I first heard it here, and I apparently joined in 2011.

Comment: Part of the reason you might hear other people use it on here is cause its used so much. I don't hear people refer to BSO's as BSO's offline around here, but most people who do care enough about biking do not ride BSO's in the first place.

Comment: It may be that Sheldon Brown (pbuh) did not think it appropriate to imply that people who cannot afford a LBS bike should not take up cycling.

Comment: I am from a Spanish speaking country, and in the streets I've never heard a similar terminology. (I learned the BSO concept here in S.E.) However, here we have a very, very popular brand of BSO, (Let's rename it to "Brandini" to preserve its privacy ;-) ) So when people refer to low quality bikes of other brands the usual is to say "It is a Brandini type of bike".
Here if you'd say "Objeto en Forma de Bici" people around you would interpret it as some decorative object, like a keychain, a trophy, etc.

Comment: I feel like BSNYC (BikeSnob NYC) used this in at least one of his books, but I believe his first wasn't published until 2010, which that google ngram search doesn't cover.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just answering the first question, google says the first use was in January 2001 in the UK:

[image: Google screenshot]

They link to [WhyCycle](http://www.whycycle.co.uk/buying-a-bike/beware-the-bicycle-shaped-object/) which refers to a page by [TheCyclingExperts](http://www.thecyclingexperts.co.uk/get-cycling/buying-a-bike/the-bicycle-shaped-object/) titled "The Bicycle Shaped Object." Since both sites are UK sites, the first use on the internet seems to be from the UK in 2001.

It's not clear if the Cycling Experts came up with the term themselves or if it was in use before 2001.... I'm actually surprised that Sheldon wasn't the originator.

Sidenote:  This [other site dated 2009](http://thecyclingblog.com/bso-bicycle-shaped-object/) also says that the term originated in the UK:

[image: Cycle Blog UK]

Comment: +1: I am cautious of this approach as in my experience, the internet often attributes historical events to the first event widely recorded on the internet (usually the first happening is recorded between 1995 and 2000ish, when the internet  became widely used)  and the myth self perpetuates.

Comment: I agree, so I hope someone can use a different methodology to find an earlier use. But at least we have a baseline of 2001 -- so any earlier than that will override this one.

Comment: It looks like there are older uses on uk.rec.cycling, but the only site I can find with a sensible search is usenetarchive and I ran out of free searches before I could pin anything down -- If anyone has access to soemthign better it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 14):

In German, I have never heard anything similar. I think one reason is that everyday cycling is more common and many people have a cheap, battered bike to get to the railway station or the local shop, so you could argue that most bicycles you see in town would be seen as BSOs by UK cyclists. It doesn't make sense to invent a new term for something that is common and already has a name.

When you observe bikes in town, in the UK (where I live now) you can rather clearly see two distinct groups: high-end bikes for the sports market (and people dressed accordingly) versus really cheap ones (often students in uni towns). In Germany it's much more a continuous spectrum with a lot of middle ground of various urban bikes, so it would be difficult to draw a boundary.

Most people buy bikes in the local bike shops, but shops tend to have a wide variety from cheap, simple, factory-built ones to high-end custom-built, so the fact that they are sold in LBSs isn't necessarily a criterium for quality or price.

Another factor is that "BSO" is a term that is a bit arrogant and derogatory, sends the message: "You are not doing it properly", which is what bike advocacy groups really want to avoid. In Germany, cycling is very much seen and promoted as everyday activity, and the cycling groups want to avoid terminology that would people off. It's better if people cycle on a cheap bike than not cycle at all. It's possible that the cycling sports community in Germany has derogatory terms for non-sportists, but I don't think it's common outside. Again, in UK the community is different and more sports-oriented (although that's beginning to change, in the last 5 years or so).

Comment: I think you make some good points (so +1) but the cheap, battered bikes can actually be good quality but old and not well looked after (e.g. one of mine).  Although you can't do much about complete rubbish components ("brake shaped objects"?), even a BSO put together by a bike shop will be better than the same bike bought in a supermarket and assembled by a novice.  Do you have a term for the supermarket bike? Aldi-special? I've seen that applied to bike accessories here in the UK.

Comment: @ChrisH Good point, of course the battered bikes can be good quality (I have one like that too...). I guess what I mean is that it's not so easy to see what's cheap and what isn't (unless you're an expert with lot of knowledge about components), whereas in UK there's more a distinction between those who don't care much versus enthusiasts with good bikes who also keep them clean and shiny, so they obviously look good. "Aldi bike" ("Aldirad") is good suggestion, sounds familiar, although I think they are not so common (Aldi sells more accessories than full bikes).

Comment: The only term I remember hearing is "Baumarktrad" (hardware store bike). I don't know how common the term is.

Comment: I assume Germany has better safety laws and better enforcement of laws to prevent 50-100 euro bikes from being sold at discount supermarkets. Heck, you don't even have that many discount supermarkets!

Comment: I'd like to blame consumer protection laws. Germans often actually ride their bikes and it isn't good business to sell bikes that need to be replaced after a few weeks.

Comment: Most bikes that you see in a _British_ town are BSOs. I imagine it's the same in most or all western countries: large retailers dominate and only people with specialist needs go to specialist retailers.

Comment: I've lived in a couple of places were the cheap commuter bike that you can treat terribly and no one wants to steal is normal.

Comment: @RoboKaren Even with a 200 Euro bike, the money is not enough to buy half-decent components. I recently built a bike from scratch, and the components were more than 500 Euros without frame and rear wheel. Obviously, factories get better prices than I do, but you won't see decent lights, brake pads, tires, etc. on a 200 Euro bike. And that's the point where I'd use the term BSO: When the components are so cheap that they cannot really do their job (like halogen lamps, for instance).

Answer (score 7):

In Russia, the term for BSO is "ашанбайк" (ashan-bike).

It's named after one big supermarket which primarily sells food, but also BSOs.
There are a lot of places in Russia where it's possible to find BSOs, but specialized bicycle stores usually don't sell them.

BSOs are rarely seen on streets (at least in St.Petersburg), probably because riding BSOs is harder than bicycles and people just give up and use public transport instead, because in Russia public transport is cheap. This may change in near future though.

Answer (score 6):

In Poland "BSO" term is not widely recognized, nor used. This site is the very first place I've encountered it. I guess in non-english speaking world the situation is similar.

If one will translate this term to polish, taking into account cultural context, it would be "wyrób roweropodobny", what, when translated back, whould mean: "bike-like product", "bike substitute product", "fake bicycle", as we had "fake chocolate", "fake cheese" and so to describe cheap substitute of some goods. This term is not widely used.

What is widely used as equivalent of "BSO" in Poland is "rower marketowy", what, generally speaking, means: "bicycle from supermarket".

The polish translation of "bicycle" whould be "bicykl", BUT this word is rather old fasioned and obsolete. We use word "rower", which comes from polonified name of british company "Rover" owned by John Starley, that were exporting its early production here in 1885.

Comment: If you mentioned a "supermarket bike" in English ("Walmart bike" in the US)  that would give a very similar impression to BSO.

Comment: "Department store bike" might give a similar impression in the US. It would be more general than "Walmart" bike. A side note: Walmart now appears to have a private label brand, Viathlon, which actually sells quite well-specced performance bikes. They will sell at Walmart.com, although these won't be stocked in stores.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer from India...

BSO (Bicyle Shaped Object) is a term virtually unknown here

Even hobbyists and serious cyclists are usually not aware of this term

The only people who know about it are the ones like me, who spend time reading about bicycling when not riding out there!

What do we call a bicycle? A *Cycle*

A Bike is a motorbike!

Supermarkets don't sell bicycles here, only LBSs (Local Bike Shop) do

We do have our share of bad bicycles but they do not even come close to the worthlessness of a BSO

MTB style frames? Cheap dual suspensions? Y-Frames? Glittering multi-coloured stickers?
We have them all but they still are not BSOs!

Because, they never have bad brakes and other critical components

They are just bad bicyles, but they can easily withstand a few thousand kilometres and harsh tropical climate without much fuss

The worst we get is rattling noises from loose metal mudguards and creaking noises from the cheap suspensions

What do we call them? Cheap cycles

Comment: This would explain why a lot of people from India post off-topic question about motorcycles here.

Comment: Good for you guys to actually get good brakes on all bikes. You seem to have your priorities sorted right :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm from the UK and we definitely use the expression BSO and I've certainly known the term since the very early 90's. As other posters have said, it normally denotes a very cheap bike from a department store or chain store and can be recognised by nearly always being made from poorly MIG welded steel tubing rather than the TIG welded alloy, cromoly or even titanium of more expensive 'proper' bicycles.

Comment: welcome to b.se! Do you have any evidence for BSO existing pre-2001 - which is the earliest anyone else had found? If you can post something definite, I'd love to award you the correct answer.

Comment: Nothing concrete. I was a student in Scotland in the very early 90's and me and all my mates rode custom mountain bikes and really lived the 'bike life' because we were students and didn't have cars. We used the term then, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very useful term and really ought to be more widely-known.

I believe it originated with a shop in Brighton, England, called South Coast Bikes. Certainly that is where I first heard it. I used it yesterday to an acquaintance who did not know it. This led to me looking for the original, which led to me finding this question before I found the answer.

Here's an updated, sadly undated, web page that the shop have extracted from their own blog explaining why buying a BSO is a bad idea:
https://www.southcoastbikes.co.uk/No_BSO.asp

Note that the comments go back to 2006. I think this page's content was adapted from an older page and I think the term goes back to the turn of the century.

Comment: Another answer has 2001 as the earliest found reference, so if yours dates from 2006 then it may have been influenced by others.

Comment: @RoboKaren As I said, the page is undated, and I believe that the content was adapted from an older page. I did quite a lot of digging before posting this answer and as someone who has been using the term "BSO" myself for at least 1½ decades, I think it's older.

Comment: Additionally, note that the BSO explanation I posted is from a bike shop: South Coast Cycles. The "BSO blog" is run by Mark Brown (https://twitter.com/MarkBrown25). As his profile states, he works for Evans Cycles, a competing company. This is why the blog carefully avoids giving credit: they are avoiding given a recommendation to a competing business. Shame on them for this, and doubly so for not being more open about the reasons.